# Django websockets connection failed

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels, linode

I have hosted a django application on Linode which includes a chatting functionality. I am using django-channels to implement that functionality. I am not using any particular
technology like Redis, just the inbuilt django thing to implement the websockets because I am just testing the site for now. The following is the chatroom.html file:

```
{% extends 'common_anime_chat/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block stylesheet %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'chatroom.css' %}">
{% endblock stylesheet %}
{% block content %}

<div class="chat-container">
    <div id="chat-messages" style='height: 75vh;'></div>
    <div id="input-container">
        <textarea id="input" rows="1"></textarea>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
</div>

{{ request.user.username|json_script:"user_username" }}
{{ request.user.profile.profile_picture.url|json_script:"user_pfp"}}
<script>
    const hardcodedProfilePictures = {
        'itsmyname': '/media/profile_pictures/profile1.png',
        'user123': '/media/profile_picturues/profile2.png',
        // Add more hardcoded profile pictures here for other usernames
    };

    document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function (e) {
        const messageInputDOM = document.querySelector('#input');
        const message = messageInputDOM.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'username': userUsername,
            'user_pfp':userPfp,
            'room_name':roomName
        }));
        messageInputDOM.value = '';
    };

    const chatMessagesDOM = document.querySelector('#chat-messages');
    const userUsername = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_username').textContent);
    // console.log(userUsername)
    const pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    const roomName = pathArray[pathArray.length - 2]; // Use -1 if the room name is in the last segment

    let userPfp = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_pfp').textContent);

    // Object to store profile pictures associated with usernames
    let profilePictures = {};

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://') +
        window.location.host +
        '/chat/' +
        roomName +
        '/'
    );
    chatSocket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
};
console.log('WebSocket URL:', chatSocket.url);

chatSocket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
};

chatSocket.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket error:', error);
};


    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    const messageContainer = document.createElement('div');
    messageContainer.classList.add('chat-message');

    let profilePicture = document.createElement('img');
    profilePicture.src = data.user_pfp;
    profilePicture.alt = 'Profile Picture';
    profilePicture.style.maxHeight = '42px';
    profilePicture.style.borderRadius = '50%';
    profilePicture.classList.add('profile-picture');
    messageContainer.appendChild(profilePicture);

    const messageContent = document.createElement('span');
    messageContent.classList.add('message-content');

    const usernameSpan = document.createElement('span');
    usernameSpan.classList.add('username');
    usernameSpan.textContent = data.username + ': ';
    usernameSpan.style.color = 'white';
    messageContent.appendChild(usernameSpan);

    const messageSpan = document.createElement('span');
    messageSpan.textContent = data.message;
    messageSpan.style.color = 'white';
    messageContent.appendChild(messageSpan);

    messageContainer.appendChild(messageContent);

    chatMessagesDOM.appendChild(messageContainer);
};

    // Fetch and load profile pictures for each user
    fetch('/api/get_user_profile_pictures/') // Change this URL to the endpoint that provides profile picture URLs for all users
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            profilePictures = data;
            console.log(profilePictures)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(profilePictures)
            console.error('Error loading profile pictures:', error);
        });
    document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            // Prevent the default behavior of Enter key (form submission)
            event.preventDefault();

            // Trigger the click event of the submit button
            document.querySelector('#submit').click();
        }
});
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

The following is the routing.py file:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

The following is the output in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://my.ip.address/chat/AUdZzo8slKKwKvzmUrnmLRfnVkuAYfJj/' failed:
(anonymous) @ (index):92
(index):109 WebSocket error: Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …}
```

The site was working perfectly fine along with the Websockets on localhost.

Although it's highly unlikely that there's an error in my consumers.py file cuz I don't think the code flow is even reaching there, the following is the consumers.py file:

```
import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from .models import ChatRoom, Message, Profile
from asyncer import asyncify

@sync_to_async
def save_message_to_database(chatroom_name, username, message):
    try:
        chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.get(name=chatroom_name)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        new_message = Message.objects.create(chat_room=chatroom, sender=user_profile, content=message)
        print("Message saved to DB:", new_message)

    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"Chatroom with name '{chatroom_name}' does not exist.")
   
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"User profile with username '{username}' does not exist.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while saving the message: {e}")
@sync_to_async
def get_chatroom_by_name(name):
    try:
        return ChatRoom.objects.get(name=name)
    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        return None
@sync_to_async
def get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom):
    return list(Message.objects.filter(chat_room=chatroom).order_by('timestamp'))

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
       
        await self.accept()
        print("Before getting chatroom")
        chatroom = await get_chatroom_by_name(self.room_name)
       
        print("chatroom:",chatroom)
   
        print("Chatroom:",chatroom)
        messages = await get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom.id)
        for message in messages:
            print("SENDING MESSAGE TO FUNCTION")
            await self.send_message_to_client(message)
       


    async def send_message_to_client(self, message):
        user_id = await sync_to_async(lambda: message.sender.user_id)()
        user = await sync_to_async(lambda: User.objects.get(id=user_id))()
        print("SENDING MESSAGES TO THE FRONTEND")
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message.content,
            'username': user.username,
            'user_pfp': message.sender.profile_picture.url,
            'room_name': self.room_name,
        }))
   
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        username = text_data_json['username']
        user_pfp = text_data_json['user_pfp']
        room_name = text_data_json['room_name']

        await save_message_to_database(chatroom_name=room_name, username=username, message=message)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chatroom_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': username,
                'user_pfp': user_pfp,
                'room_name': room_name,
                'tester_message': 'tester message in receive function'
            }
        )

    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']
        user_pfp = event['user_pfp']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
            'user_pfp': user_pfp,
            'tester_message': 'tester message in chatroom message'
        }))
```

Please help me out with this problem!